# Statistical analysis of two same experimental measurements

Tags: statistical-significance, uncertainty

Say I have two blood samples (Sample A and Sample B).

Now, I want to do a measurement (dependent variable, let's call it *D*) on both samples, at 5 different levels of mechanical stress (independent variable, let's call it *I*). However, since some calculations is involved to get *D* and *I*, and also since the devices have some uncertainty, both dependent and independent variables are reported as: *I*+/-U1   and  *D*+/-U2, where U1 and U2 are the total uncertainties for independent and dependent variables, respectively.

U1 is composed of device uncertainty only (which is actually the error propagation).

U2 is composed of device uncertainty and repeated measurement uncertainty.

Say, we want to do 10 measurements at each of the 5 different stress levels (for both samples A and B).

Note that, when I plot *D* vs. *I*, there will be both vertical and horizontal bars for the uncertainty.

Now, I want to see if the difference between D in sample A is significantly different than that in the sample B at each stress level.

What kind of statistical test should I use?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This problem is unsolvable, unless you can make some prior assumptions. You need to know

1. The probability distributions of your measurement and device uncertainties
2. If these distributions are independent, or otherwise, what exactly the dependence relation is

If you can assume the most simple case, namely

1. Both distributions are normal, where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are standard deviations of the distributions
2. The probability distributions are independent

Then you could use [chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) test to determine if your data is likely under the assumption that both samples $A$ and $B$ share the same mean. Namely, you would compute

$$
\chi^2 =
\bigl(\frac{I_A - \mu_I}{U_{1A}}\bigr)^2 
+ \bigl(\frac{I_B - \mu_I}{U_{1B}}\bigr)^2 
+ \bigl(\frac{D_A - \mu_D}{U_{2A}}\bigr)^2 
+ \bigl(\frac{D_B - \mu_D}{U_{2B}}\bigr)^2 
$$

then find the $\mu_I$, and $\mu_D$ that minimize the above expression and plug them back into the expression for $\chi^2$. Finally, the resulting expression can be compared with the tabulated value for $\chi^2$ of dimension $2$ to determine the p-value.

Comment: Thanks for the info! How can I know if the device uncertainty has normal distribution?

Comment: And also how I know the distributions are independent?

Comment: The easiest way to check is to measure D and I for one and the same sample like 100 times and plot the marginal and joint probability distributions of D and I. If the joint distribution is equal to the product of the marginal distributions, then they are independent, otherwise not. Also, you can directly compare your marginal distributions to gaussian distributions and see how well they match. Then, I would repeat the same process of measuring a few different samples like 100 times each. This is necessary because errors could be dependent on the mean values of D and I

Comment: You don't have to do this procedure every time you measure D and I, it is only necessary to determine the probability distribution of errors and calculate U1 and U2. Afterwards a single measurement per sample might be sufficient, if your errors are not too large. Also, the number 100 I said is arbitrary, it depends on how confident you want to be on in your conclusions